# Can't log in/out using Devise and JQuery Mobile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, authentication, devise

Im currently trying to adapt my Views to a Mobile Plattform. But i am experiencing some Problems.

I've been using the Gem Mobylette for Mobile-Device-Detection.
Devise for Authentication and JQuery-Mobile for the layout.

Everything works fine so far, but logging in and out makes some Problems.

This is my new.erb.mobile:

```
<h2>Sign in</h2>
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true %></div>

  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
    <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "off" %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>
```

If the user trys to submit from a mobile plattform the following error occurs:

```
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template devise/sessions/create, devise/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:mobile], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
```

i found a fix for this. I simple have to create a create.mobile.erb and redirect manually inside this file like so:

```
<section id="login_redirect_page" data-role="page"> 
  <script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "<%= root_path %>"
  </script>
</section>
```

but logging out still does not work.
This is how the generated Code looks like :

```
<a class="navbar-link ui-link ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="nofollow" data-role="button" role="button">Logout</a>
```

But if i try to logout there is just a spinning circle that appears and no redirection happens.

I really don't know what i am doing wrong and i didn't found a solution for this Problem on the Internet so maybe someone here knows what i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after struggeling with this issue a day or so i finally found the right solution including no manual redirects or ajax stuff:

1. Add a new Initializer to your config/initializers and add the following lines to it :

   ActionController::Responder.class_eval do
     alias :to_mobile :to_html
   end
2. Register the Mobile Type inside the devise configuration block :

   config.navigational_formats = [:"*/*", "*/*", :html, :mobile]

Answer (score 0):

This is a wild shot but lets try it, in your form element add this attribute:

```
data-ajax=”false”
```

This is because jQuery Mobile by default uses it own way of handling form submition, read more about it **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/how-to-correctly-submit-form-data-in-jquery-mobile/)**. Basically this attribute will prevent jQuery Mobile from hijacking this feature.

Comment: Added this to logging in form and it works but if wanna log out it does not work : This is the generated code : <a class="navbar-link ui-link ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false" data-method="delete" href="/users/sign_out" rel="external nofollow" data-role="button" role="button">Logout</a> ..

Comment: @SebastianBoldt also have same problem.. data-ajax=”false” only not working on logout . else works perfactly in whole site.. hope your solution works